# ParametricPlot3D does not export with the specified PlotRange?

Tags: export, graphics3d

I am trying to plot a function with ParametricPlot3D with a specified plot range to export as an stl file, however when exporting the graphic mathematica ignores the PlotRange and exports the whole function, is there a way to make this work or some sort of intersection command to work around this?
[image: Mathematica Function]

[image: Resulting Export]

Comment: Could you include the code you used for exporting to STL?

Comment: I have the same problem when you cannot simply replace the PlotRange by restricting the parameter domain.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/48072)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Ivan Sterling, you cannot simply restrict the `PlotRange`, as this will not be respected when exporting to "STL".  Take Louis's example,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
   Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, π}, {0, π}, All}]
Export["test.stl", %] // Import
```

[image]

One method to make sure that you only get the plot you want is to restrict the parameter values, only plotting over the relevant values of `u` and `v`.  But another option is to supply a [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
   Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 0 <= x <= π && 0 <= y <= π]]
Export["test.stl", %] // Import
```

[image]

Comment: Nice example +1

Answer (score 0):

Works as intended on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014), see also [STL (.stl)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/STL.html)

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]

Export["MathematicaParametricSurface.stl", pp1]
```

[image]

[image]

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 1 Pi}, {v, 0, 1 Pi}]

Export["MathematicaParametricSurface.stl", pp1]
```

[image]

[image]

```
Import["MathematicaParametricSurface.stl"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  Your problem is your looking at the "true points" not the adjusted points.

See Mathematica BoxRatios[{1,1,1}].  I think that will do it.

If it doesn't all I can say is see the following which will (can) do it.  (you can adjust the rayshade.m if needed to suite the need of your renderer, by default rayshade` uses plain text scaling for BoxRatio - your renderer may or may not like that.  it also contains ability that can be utilized (not automatically) to scale the actual points).  That being said: you can just scale the points using Mathematica yourself BEFORE you export!  It's easy just multiply all the vertex by a scaling vertex.

see:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rayshade-math/

[How to Render, raytrace, Export Graphics3D in Mathematica 11.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146423/how-to-render-raytrace-export-graphics3d-in-mathematica-11-0)

Comment: " I think that will do it." - have you tried?